# How to call helper function observer in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, helper

I am trying to call `helper` function on observer custom module in `Magento2` but Unable to call helper in **observer**.

Please help me if anybody have this solution. I am waiting for all your positive response.

Comment: show us what you tried. normaly oyu just have to inject it into the constructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like below in your observer file.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalableObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    ...

    protected $dataHelper;

    ...

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Custom\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        ...
    }

    public function ...(){
        $helper = $this->dataHelper;
    }

    ...
}

?>
```